# gcc: Find directory of libstdc++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I am writing a C library which needs to statically link with a library written in C++. I can specify the location of `libstdc++.a` explicitly (since I am linking statically):

```
gcc main.c /some/library.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.a
```

I found the location for `libstdc++.a` by using the following:

```
$ g++ --print-file-name=libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.a
```

This is good and all, except for the fact that it uses `g++` to find it. If I do the following with `gcc` instead:

```
$ gcc --print-file-name=libstdc++.a
libstdc++.a
```

It cannot find it. Am I missing something? Is `gcc` capable of doing this, or do I have to use `g++`?

Comment: It works here on NixOS, both ``g++`` and ``gcc`` return the full path to the static lib.

Answer (score 1):

STL (another name of the library), is native to C++. It is written in C++. So, gcc does not have any built in support for STL.
g++ support for STL is built in.